# How to extract private keys from an ssh-agent?

Tags: encryption, key-management, ssh-agent

`ssh-add -l` displays that I have 3 RSA keys added to my SSH agent.

`ssh-add -L` displays those public keys.

How do I get the private keys as well, so that I can save them to a file? Or is it by design that this is impossible? How does it work then?

Can ssh-agent be asked to do operations using the private key? How can I ask it to encrypt/decrypt a number for me?

It's OK that I have to write code for this (the programming language doesn't matter), but I'd prefer using an existing tool or a library.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**It's not possible to get the private key or to perform encryption using the protocol between ssh and ssh-agent, but it's possible to get the private key by dumping the memory of the ssh-agent. On Linux you have to be root to do the memory dump.**

I've just found a very good explanation about how ssh-agent works: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html . This partially answers some of my questions.

- One of the more clever aspects of the agent is how it can verify a user's identity (or more precisely, possession of a private key) without revealing that private key to anybody.
- One of the security benefits of agent forwarding is that the user's private key never appears on remote systems or on the wire, even in encrypted form.

Thus the protocol between the SSH client and the ssh-agent proviedes no way in SSH1 or SSH2 to get out the private keys from an ssh-agent.

However, as root you can get a memory dump of ssh-agent, and try to extract the private key from there. https://blog.netspi.com/stealing-unencrypted-ssh-agent-keys-from-memory does exactly that, and there are other pieces of software mentioned in the comment section of that page. However, the software on that page didn't work for me on Debian buster: the memory dump didn't contain any keys, even though `ssh-add -l` has displayed an RSA key.

Comment: That is not really an answer to the question - namely, whether there is any way to ask ssh-agent for its decrypted keys, for example to feed them to some other SSH client which does not know how to use ssh-agent.

Comment: The answer to the question: no, it's not possible. What's possible lis listed in the linked document, and this one isn't.

Comment: Quite contrary, _everything_ is possible in a virtual world, it just depends on the time and effort to achieve the goal.  For example, this is how you can extract/steal keys from ssh-agent: https://blog.netspi.com/stealing-unencrypted-ssh-agent-keys-from-memory/

Comment: @galaxy: Thank you for the link! I've added it to my answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR:
**Using [this](https://github.com/Kracken256/ssh-keyfinder) tool, you can automate the extraction of SSH private keys from an SSH agent memory dump (as root).**

This tool can extract multiple SSH private keys from the ssh-agent at once. It supports SSH RSA and SSH ED25519 private key types.

It works, as described in the blogs posts mentioned above, by searching for a magic string in the memory, finding structures, parsing several structures to locate the shielded private key, and unshielded (decode) the private key memory bytes into an SSH format printed to the screen.

The private keys outputted from this tool are unencrypted and can be used directly to connect to your servers.

See the projects README file for more info.

https://github.com/Kracken256/ssh-keyfinder

**Discloser:** I am on author of this tool.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I accidentally deleted the .ssh folder but my keys are loaded. But since I can't recover those from ssh-add so I had to use file recovery software.

Comment: As an alternative of disk recovery software, you can dump the memory of a running Linux process (e.g. *ssh-agent*) as root (`sudo cat /proc/$$/mem`, but add proper seeking). Probably disk recovery software is easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

If on Windows 10, apparently the method described in [this blog post](https://blog.ropnop.com/extracting-ssh-private-keys-from-windows-10-ssh-agent/) worked in 2018. The author links to proof-of-concept code on github:

> tl;dr
>
> Private keys are protected with DPAPI and stored in the HKCU registry hive. I released some PoC code [here](https://github.com/ropnop/windows_sshagent_extract) to extract and reconstruct the RSA private key from the registry

Answer (score -10):

You probably don't need to. Most likely you just want a public key:

```
ssh-add -L > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: In this question I ask for the private key. I already mention `ssh-add -L` in the question to extract the public key.

Comment: I wouldn't blindly redirect any output to `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, because it may destroy useful data already in the file.