# Can't connect SSH with paramiko to a Google Compute Engine instance

Tags: python, ssh, google-compute-engine, sftp, paramiko

I found a lot of similar questions here in SO, but any of them helped me, even this problem seems to be simple.

I'm trying to connect to a remote Google Compute Engine instance through SSH (I want to use SFTP) using paramiko. Below is my code:

```
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.load_system_host_keys()
        client.connect('External_IP_Get_In_GCE_panel', username='myuser')
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls')
        for line in stdout:
            print('... ' + line.strip('\n'))
        client.close()
```

With this code, I have the error

> PasswordRequiredException: Private key file is encrypted

When I tried `client.connect('External_IP_Get_In_GCE_panel', username='myuser', password='')` the error is:

> BadAuthenticationType: ('Bad authentication type', [u'publickey']) (allowed_types=[u'publickey'])

My SSH key to access Google Compute engine has no password. I can use the `gcloud compute ssh instance-name` and also access SFTP throug Filezilla without problems.

As I said, I tried a lot of alternatives found here in SO, but any of them helped me. Below are 3 other versions of the code:

*Using key*

```
    key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=base64.b64decode(b"""AAAAB3Nza..."""))
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.get_host_keys().add('External_IP_Get_In_GCE_panel', 'ssh-rsa', key)
    client.connect('External_IP_Get_In_GCE_panel', username='myuser', password='')
    # I got the key using ssh-keyscan `External_IP_Get_In_GCE_panel`in my local machine
```

*Using another lib*

```
    key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=decodebytes(keydata))
    cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
    cnopts.hostkeys.add('External_IP_Get_In_GCE_panel', 'ssh-rsa', key)

    with pysftp.Connection('External_IP_Get_In_GCE_panel', username='myuser', cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
        with sftp.cd('../directory'):
            sftp.get('remote_file')'''
```

Using the ssh key file

```
    self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    self.client.connect(hostname="External_IP_Get_In_GCE_panel", username="myuser", key_filename=os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/ssh_key_file'), password='') # also tried ssh_key_file.pub
```

In all this versions (and some others) I tried to use `password=''`, `password=None` and not send password argument. The results is always the same erros above.

Any tip about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *key is encrypted*, you need a password (and presumably non-empty so) to [*decrypt* the private key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15579117/918959), i.e.

```
key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=base64.b64decode(b"""AAAAB3Nza..."""), password='my key password')
```

The server there only allows public key authentication, so giving `password` to `client.connect` does not make any sense.

Comment: As I said, the SSH key was created without password, so I don't have anything to fill this parameter and `password=''` with blank string raises the same error of encrypted private key.

Comment: @James it seems to have a password - perhaps you're confusing "no password" with "sshagent remembers the password"

Comment: @James or try an empty password in call to `RSAKey`.

Comment: I created the key and didn't type anything for the passphrase, so I'm pretty sure that this key does not have password. Anyway, I'll try your solution and maybe create a new key with password to avoid this type of problem. Thanks for your help.